# C++ call stack not in standard?

Tags: c++, stack, standards

Does the C++ standard talk about the call stack? It's common knowledge how stack and heap are used in C++, but I was reading through the standard and found no mention of it.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf

Is this something that's left up to the compiler implementation, but everyone agrees on, or did I miss something while browsing the doc?

Comment: Stealth down-vote? Please explain why this question is invalid...

Answer (score 5):

It isn't mentioned in the standard. Neither the stack nor the heap are. The standard describes the syntax and the semantics(the behavior) of C++ programs. The implementations choose to implement it as they wish.

However when you see how calls to functions must behave, there isn't a really wide choice. There has to be some sort of a stack to store local variables!

Comment: It is needed only if there are recursive calls, otherwise each function *could* have a fixed location for its variables.

Comment: @Nikolay: That fits into "some sort of stack" category :)

Comment: Well, yes. Or some sort of "ring buffer" category, or ... :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard talks about [**storage duration**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) instead of stack and heap. How those are implemented is up to ... implementation.