# C++ Local var in dynamic, on stack?

Tags: c++, dynamic, stack, local

Say i have a object in dynamic memory (new) and inside one of its functions, it has

```
int Obj1::Add(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

Is c (and a and b...) on the stack ? or in dynamic memory with my object. Just curious :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of those will be on the stack. `a` and `b` are passed parameters so, even if the originals were in the heap, a copy would be made on the stack. If you were passing by reference, it may be a different matter since the thing actually sent across ("under the hood") would be more of a pointer to the original.

For `c`, since it's a local variable, it's on the stack too.

That's of course assuming your implementation even *uses* a stack, and that optimisation hasn't just stashed them into registers. It's really totally up to the implementation.

Comment: `a` and `b` are parameters, so they will probably not be on the stack, except on an extremely register poor architecture like Intel.  On a Sparc or an AMD 64 bit processor, they will be in registers.  (And with any decent optimizer, `c` will be in a register as well.)

Comment: I can easily write a standard conforming implementation that passes all its arguments as a pointer to a dynamically allocated struct (not that I see any good reasons for doing so), so I really wouldn't say in "any" case it won't be on the heap ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no explicit mention of the terms "stack" or "heap" in the C++ standard.  Instead a C++ compiler is required to implement things in terms of a certain "storage duration":

[C++ call stack not in standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876043/c-call-stack-not-in-standard)

But for practical purposes with the processors and compilers of today, you can generally assume a/b/c are on the stack or in registers.

Answer (score 3):

It's really up to the compiler.  On a Sparc, all three will be in registers, and I would expect this to be the most frequent case.  Only on an Intel 32 bit (or 16 bit, if you go back in time) would `a` and `b` be on the stack.

None of which is relevant to much of anything.  Concerning the key point of your question (I think): none of them will be part of the object referenced by `this`.  However the compiler organizes things, the three variables will be somewhere else than the object.  Even if the object itself is on the stack, and you're on an Intel architecture where arguments, etc. are also on the stack, the object and the variables will be in different places on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

`a`, `b` and `c` are on the stack (or potentially in registers).

Answer (score 0):

They are all on the stack. However, it's still safe to return c to the caller because a copy will be made.